# Why does connecting Positive directly to Ground cause problems?

Tags: battery-charging, electricity

So I am extremely confused at this point. From my understanding, connecting a 5v directly to Ground will causes problems, but why?

A 5v battery is asking for 5v and x amount of current, but yet it cant handle that amount of voltage and current it asked for.

Does all the voltage need to be used by the end of the circuit to prevent problems?

Comment: You CAN connect "5V" to ground safely ... provided you don't also connect "0V" to ground (and can guarantee it isn't connected e.g. through the chassis somehow). Then the "5V" terminal on your battery is effectively 0V, and its "0V" terminal is -5V. It's just very confusing for the unwary - but there are a few "positive ground" systems ... http://www.restore-an-old-car.com/positive-ground-cars.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a lot of current generates a lot of heat and that's how you burn stuff.

Ohm's law states that:

$$I=\frac{V}{R}$$

Where *I* is the current measured in Amperes(A), *V* is the Voltage or potential difference measured in Volts(V) and *R* is the Resistance measured in Ohms(Ω).

If the resistance from +5V to GND is very small, the denominator becomes very close to zero and *I* becomes massively large.

When you touch a voltage source to ground (or short the two poles of a battery if you prefer) you see sparks. That is the electric current breaking through the air.

Even though you don't see a resistance, there is always resistance in any system no matter how small it may be. For example, a battery has internal resistance. Imagine resistance as something stopping the battery from emptying all at the same time. Even if you short-circuit it, it will take some time to empty. (It will also heat up very quickly and some types of battery may even ignite or explode.) Thats because of internal battery resistance.

Another way of thinking about it is thinking of voltage as height. +5V is higher than ground. If you have a bucket full of water with a hole on the bottom, a current of water will flow. How much depends on the size of the hole. If the hole is closed, you have infinite resistance so no water flows.

To answer your last question, yes. We say that the '*drop*' across R1 is 5V. So if you were an electron at the ground, you are raised 5V by the battery and you drop 5V *through* the resistor to complete you circle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffLpyB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: "If the resistance from +5v to GND is very small, the denominator becomes very close to zero." That part of the answer did it for me! It makes a lot of sense now. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A short circuit = a wire or any other too low resistance load between the poles of a voltage source or two nodes of a powered circuit.

"Too low resistance" = causes the voltage to drop unusable for its original purposes due the internal resistance of the source

OR

Causes so high current that some part in the circuit gets hot and is destroyed (the rechargeable batteries are extremely dangerous in this sense)

OR both of them.

The current regulation prevents the "getting too hot" case. Fuses are the other way to protect.

Innumerable amount of fires, deaths and equipment destructions are caused by short circuits - some of them accidentally, some by using bad parts, some by an intentional action that was not understood and some  intentionally to cause harm.

Maybe you should as soon as possible learn the basics about voltage, current and Ohms law. Until that avoid messing around electric circuits without competent quidance.

Your writing shows that you and the people nearby really should be afraid of your actions with electricity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason the positive terminal can't be connected to ground has been answered, but just in case, to clarify, ground is just a reference point in a circuit. There are cases when a circuit is literally connected to ground (and thus Earth surface's potential), but in the case of a 5 V power source circuit, this probably isn't what the ground terminal indicates on your schematic. Here's an interesting wikipedia page that sums it up:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_(electricity)

So if ground isn't a connection to "the actual ground" what is it? In the case of a 5V battery source, it is the negative end of the battery if you want to imagine the top of the battery as +5 Volts. The ground often isn't labelled right at the bottom of the battery, but it will be nearby on a "resistance-less" connection (lines in a schematic don't have any resistance, they are merely connections). Example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5OrqI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That still might seem confusing, so what is voltage? Voltage is the energy, or work, per charge.  This can be derived from the equation. In mechanics Work = Force * Distance (ignoring integration a moment for simplicity). With Electricity Voltage = Electric_field * Distance. Coulomb's law states that F = k (q1 * q2)/r^2 *ar (where ar is an ugly unit vector symbol). The electric field is similar- E = k(q)/r^2 *ar. And for any test charge in the field (q_t) this creates a force F = q_t * E = k(q* q_t)/r^2 *ar. So, knowing that F = qE it makes sense that voltage is energy or work by substitution - q * (Voltage = Electric_field * Distance) => q V = F * d => W = F * d. Think of voltage as the electrical equivalent of mass held at a higher elevation, just another form of energy, or you can think of the bucket of water mentioned above...

Next problem, 
"A 5v battery is asking for 5v and x amount of current, but yet it cant handle that amount of voltage and current it asked for."

V = IR is ohm's law (a form of it, there's also J=oE <- o should really be sigma but 'Joe' provides such a better mnemonic...). You may have also seen P=IV. All batteries should also have a power rating. If not, you are the fortunate owner of an infinite source of power.

And lastly,
Does all the voltage need to be used by the end of the circuit to prevent problems?

You may have heard the acronym 'KVL' thrown about if you're studying electrical engineering among peers. 'KVL' stands for Kirchoff's voltage law. It states that the sum of the voltages around any closed loop must equal zero. You're confusion may be somewhat justified given the law's awkward presentation by some teachers. Take any system or electrical circuit loop and observe the energy stored (here +5V battery) and the energy lost (i*R in the above circuit's case), the sum is usually (as in always) zero. Likewise, there is no known perpetual motion machine because that's just the way the world works. The intuition makes sense when comparing 'KVL' to the conservation of energy, but beyond that one has to, as far as I know, accept that the workings of the universe are inherently axiomatic.

I hope some of that helps.

Comment: This answer is really amazing! Thanks for going in depth and explaining. Yes looking back at it now, the sum of all electrical circuits is zero!